# OTA ca3080 troubles

Tags: ota, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I having a hard time getting this OTA ca3080 circuit working as expected.
It's configured as VCA (or a amplitude modulator.
I got the circuit from here: http://www.idea2ic.com/LM13600/UsingOTAs2.pdf
I also added a buffer opamp (TL072) directly to the 'Out'. Powered by +/- 9V, sine signals coming from a 2 channel signal generator.

Because of the 100k R5 already there I assume this is enough to make convert the high impedance output to a low impedance output. (Am i right sofar??)

Not sure about the voltages I can put in I've tried every possible sine level on the input (between 0,025v up until 5 volts.) and also tried different levels on the modulation input (also different combinations and such.)
I've traced every point in between with my scope so I'm sure everything connects well.
But, no modulated sine to be seen....

In my mind it could be a few things:
- input level too loud -> gives a straight blue line because of distortion (but then, it's a sine...dailled back, no difference.)
- modulation level too loud -> distortion (dailled back on it, no difference...)

Problem: no signal level at the output. What am I missing here?

I included a scope plot (yellow is output of sine gen connected to input, blue is output of the opamp TL072)

[image: scope]

[[image: OTA ca3080 circuit[2]]

[[image: Opamp buffer TL072[3]]

Answer (score 1):

The CA3080 has un-degenerated bipolar inputs. The "linear" range will be 5 to 15 millivolts, depending on your budget for distortion.

The modulation input is just a current into a current mirror, with the mirror's output going to the diffpair.

I referred to the Vin+ and Vin-, the bases of the diffpair. For any semblance of linearity, keep that signal (the difference) down to 10 millivolts.

Make the modulation vary from -8 volts to 0 volts.

And increase the 33K to 339K

With the present circuit, the I_bias is so big --- (9v - 0.6v)/33k = 250uA, that
the output tries to move to -25 volts.

====================

wondering where is GND for the blue line?

******** [ ok I see it.] ca3080 needs resistor to its "bias" pin. where is it?

Comment: Which input do you mean? Both or just the modulation input? 5-15 millivolts from 0 volt up, or 7.5mV above zero and -7.5 mV below 0? Sorry for the detailed questions but I've been trying for days now... :-)

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could show you the new plot, but I can see on my scope it is modulating. Now I'm reading about biasing the output. My output is now modulating between 0 and 7v now. It's more making a V-shape now instead of a nice 'growing' sine wave. I assume that can be fixed adding a bias to the opamp? (which I've tried and got no to desired effect) I'd expect the R5 to be more of an issue now... (based on info here: looking a Ibias at the outputpin http://keepontouch-en.blogspot.com/2011/06/5-2-1-circuits-used-in-amplitude.html)

Comment: Could this be a possible solution to my issue? Found in  "If desired, the gain- control pin can be DC biased so that a carrier output is available with no AC input signal applied." Found in the same doc: http://www.idea2ic.com/LM13600/UsingOTAs2.pdf